# Teamcity and AWS CLI

Tags: teamcity, aws-cli

I am running Teamcity on a windows VM and have installed the awscli.

I am trying to pull a zip from aws S3. But I get this error:
" aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file"

When I run the command in both cmd and powershell it works just fine.

I have also checked that the awscli path is in both user and system paths.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The build agent was not running as a service and was running as a user account that didn't have the correct permissions. Installed a new agent, ran it as a windows service and as a service account.

I hope this helps someone in the future that faces this frustrating issue.